# why my scoped css not working on my page nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, nuxt.js

I have have a problem with my scoped css is not applied to the footer

My footer is a component I include inside my layout

here is the layout:

```html
//in my /layouts/default.vue
<template >
  <div>
    <TheNavbar />
    <Nuxt />
    <TheFooter />
  </div>
</template>
```

i want to set the footer at the bottom of the homepage so i write this:

```html
//inside the pages/home.vue
<style lang="css" scoped>
footer {
    position: fixed;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

But it doesn't work, I try add `*>>>` to search deeper but it doesn't work too.

I don't know what I did wrong, any idea?

here the footer component:

```
// in my components/TheFooter.vue
<template>
  <footer id="footer" class="lg:text-2xl mt-10">
    <div class="flex flex-col lg:flex-row">
      <div class="flex flex-grow">
        <h3 class="hidden lg:block">{{ $t('f') }}</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="flex flex-col flex-grow space-y-3">
        <h3>{{ $t('contact') }}</h3>
        <p>
          <a
            href=""
            title="Send e-mail"
            onclick="gtag('event', 'click', {'event_category': 'Contact', 'event_action': 'E-mail', 'event_label': 'E-mail address clicked'});"
            ><font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'envelope']" />
            </a
          >
        </p>
        <p>
          <a
            href=""
            title="Call"
            onclick="gtag('event', 'click', {'event_category': 'Contact', 'event_action': 'Phone', 'event_label': 'Phone number clicked'});"
            ><font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'phone']" /></a
          >
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex flex-col flex-grow space-y-3">
        <h3>{{ $t('follow') }}</h3>
        <p>
          <a
            href=""
            title="Visit Instagram profile"
            onclick="gtag('event', 'click', {'event_category': 'Contact', 'event_action': 'Instagram', 'event_label': 'Instagram link clicked'});"
            class=""
            ><font-awesome-icon :icon="['fab', 'instagram']" /> Instagram</a
          >
        </p>
        <p>
          <a
            href=""
            title="Visit LinkedIn profile"
            onclick="gtag('event', 'click', {'event_category': 'Contact', 'event_action': 'LinkedIn', 'event_label': 'LinkedIn clicked'});"
            class=""
            ><font-awesome-icon :icon="['fab', 'linkedin-in']" /> LinkedIn</a
          >
        </p>
        <p>
          <a
            href=""
            title="Visit LinkedIn profile"
            onclick="gtag('event', 'click', {'event_category': 'Contact', 'event_action': 'LinkedIn', 'event_label': 'LinkedIn clicked'});"
            class=""
            ><font-awesome-icon :icon="['fab', 'github']" /> Github</a
          >
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</template>

<script>
export default {}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Comment: Could you add the complete code of TheFooter.vue component. It will be easier to understand what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem back then. From your code I can see that you are providing the styling on the level component. Try putting the styling in the TheFooter.vue component and not in the home.vue component.

Comment: You're missing the whole point of the question here.